# RF24 communication with Arduino

Tags: raspbian, gpio, networking, hardware, rpi.gpio

I have been trying for ages to work this problem out and can't figure it out. I have two nrf24 transceivers, one connected to the raspberry pi and the other connected to an Arduino. My code for the Arduino is written using the maniacbug rf24 library and the raspberry pi is using a modified version of that (I don't remember which one but i think it was Stanely-something-or-other). When I ran my code, Before it would give me erroneous feed back and the addresses where something like 0xffffffffffff (i dont remember the count but it was f repeating). The wiring here was done as per: [image: rpi wiring]. I then rewired as it was suggested on this page http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17061&p=350040 and it looked like

```
RPi GPIO9 (Pin 21) to RF Module Pin 7 ( MISO )
RPi GPIO10 (Pin 19) to RF Module Pin 6 ( MOSI )
RPi GPIO 11 (Pin 23) to RF Module Pin 5 ( SCK )
RPi GPIO8 (Pin 24) to RF Module Pin 3 ( CE )
RPi GPIO 25 (Pin 22) to RF Module Pin 4 ( CSN )
RPI 3.3V (Pin 17) to RF Module Pin 2 ( VCC/3.3V )
RPi Gnd (Pin 25) to RF Module Pin 1 (GND)
```

How ever now, Eveything is zeroed out instead of repeating f. and I am not getting any output (before it gave me really big numbers, the max for unsigned log i believe).
I also ran the example code and same things.

This Is my radio data:

```
SPI device       = /dev/spidev0.0
SPI speed        = 8000000
CE GPIO          = 25
STATUS           = 0x00 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=0 TX_FULL=0
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0x0000000000 0x0000000000
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
TX_ADDR          = 0x0000000000
RX_PW_P0-6       = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
EN_AA            = 0x00
EN_RXADDR        = 0x00
RF_CH            = 0x00
RF_SETUP         = 0x00
CONFIG           = 0x00
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0x00 0x00
Data Rate        = 1MBPS
Model            = nRF24L01
CRC Length       = Disabled
PA Power         = PA_MIN
```

this was taken from the rpi_hub example

What Am I doing wrong? should I wire it a different way?

Edit: Here is the code. Sorry it took so long, I had everything working on two arduinos so I thought the raspberry pi would be fine. turns out it isnt =/

```
#include "../costumLibraries/RF24/librf24-rpi/librf24/RF24.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
// Command Line: g++ -Wall -Ofast -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv6zk -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -L../librf24/  -lrf24 -pthread *.cpp -o remote
using namespace std;
RF24 radio("/dev/spidev0.0",8000000 , 25);  //spi device, speed and CSN,only CSN is NEEDED in RPI
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };

void setup(void){
    //Prepare the radio module
    printf("\nPreparing interface\n");
    radio.begin();
    radio.setRetries( 15, 15);
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
    radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
    // radio.startListening();
    radio.printDetails();
    cout<<"good"<<endl;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv){
        string choice;
        // time_t timer;
        int choiceVal;
        setup();
        while(choice != "quit"){
            cout<<">";
            cin>>choice;
            cout<<endl;
            choiceVal = atoi(choice.c_str());
            if(choice!="quit"){ 
               radio.write(&choiceVal, sizeof(int));
               printf("\n\rRecieved and sent %i",choiceVal);
               radio.startListening();
               unsigned long started_waiting_at = time(NULL);
               bool timeout = false;
               while ( ! radio.available() && ! timeout )
                 if (time(NULL) - started_waiting_at > 200 )
                   timeout = true;

               // Describe the results
               if ( timeout )
               {
                 printf("Failed, response timed out.\n\r");
               }
               bool done = false;
               while (!done){
               // Fetch the payload, and see if this was the last one.
                   done = radio.read( &choiceVal, sizeof(int) );
                   printf("recieved: %i",choiceVal);
                   delay(20);
               }
               radio.stopListening();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your Pins look correct. I suspect the issue is in your code. It could be on the Raspberry Pi or Arduino side. I would suggest running the sample code that is provided in the examples folder of the source code - https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24/tree/master/examples/GettingStarted. If my memory serves me correct, the code will work on Arduino and Pi as both there C++.

Comment: I tested on two arduinos using library examples and it worked. I tried the library example (the rpi_hub one) on the Raspberry pi and That didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you have your culprit. You might want to post both codes for people to review.

Comment: @PhilVallone The Examples Didn't work on the raspberry pi. The examples worked fine on the arduinos though so the Module is fine.

Comment: You need to post the code. Otherwise there is no way someone can help

Comment: @PhilVallone The code has been posted

Comment: Which Raspberry Pi are you using?

Comment: @developius I was using the raspberry pi Model B

Comment: @ppumkin Well I never fixed it so. . .

Answer (score 1):

In case you have spare boards, try a pair of same board and run library example. Same board is easy to test first.

For information, http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/  is new library for Arduino (not sure if also available for RPi yet).

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you only posted half your code. Since you are trying to communicate between the 2, both codes are helpful. Nevertheless, try the below code. This code will communicate between the Arduino and Raspberry Pi. The Pi is the sender (Transmitter) and the Arduino is the receiver. You might need to adjust the import paths as your code is most likely in a different location.

This code was taken from the examples provided in the github repo and the examples directory of the source code:

Pin out:

```
Raspberry Pi    RF24    Name
----------------------------
GND             1       GND
3.3V            2       VCC
GPIO 25         3       CE
GPIO 8          4       CSN
GPIO 11         5       SCK
GPIO 10         6       MOSI
GPIO 09         7       MISO
                8       IRQ

Arduino     RF24    Name
------------------------
GND         1       GND
3.3V        2       VCC
9           3       CE
10          4       CSN
13          5       SCK
11          6       MOSI
12          7       MISO
                    IRQ
```

Arduino:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
#include "printf.h"

int LedOn = 8;
RF24 radio(9,10);//uno

const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E9LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };

typedef enum { role_ping_out = 1, role_pong_back } role_e;

const char* role_friendly_name[] = { "invalid", "Ping out", "Pong back"};

role_e role = role_pong_back;

void setup(void)
{

  pinMode(LedOn, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(57600);
  printf_begin();
  printf("\n\rRF24/examples/GettingStarted/\n\r");
  printf("ROLE: %s\n\r",role_friendly_name[role]);
  printf("*** PRESS 'T' to begin transmitting to the other node\n\r");

  radio.begin();

  radio.setRetries(15,15);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.printDetails();
}

void loop(void)
{

  if (role == role_ping_out)
  {   
    radio.stopListening();
    unsigned long time = millis();
    printf("Now sending %lu...",time);
    bool ok = radio.write( &time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

    if (ok)
      printf("ok...");
    else
      printf("failed.\n\r");


    radio.startListening();

    unsigned long started_waiting_at = millis();
    bool timeout = false;
    while ( ! radio.available() && ! timeout )
      if (millis() - started_waiting_at > 200 )
        timeout = true;

    if ( timeout )
    {
      printf("Failed, response timed out.\n\r");
       digitalWrite(LedOn, LOW);
    }
    else
    {

      char* mess;
      radio.read( &mess, sizeof(char*) );     
      printf("Got response %s, message is: %s\n\r",mess);      
    }

    delay(1000);
  }


  unsigned int mess;
  if ( role == role_pong_back )
  {

    if ( radio.available() )
    {
      digitalWrite(LedOn, HIGH);     
      unsigned long got_time;

      bool done = false;
      while (!done)
      {
        done = radio.read( &mess, sizeof(unsigned int) );

        printf("Got payload %lu...", mess);

        delay(30);

      }

      radio.stopListening();

      radio.write( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );
      printf("Sent response.\n\r");

      radio.startListening();
    }else{
       digitalWrite(LedOn, LOW);
    }
  }

  if ( Serial.available() )
  {
    char c = toupper(Serial.read());
    if ( c == 'T' && role == role_pong_back )
    {
      printf("*** CHANGING TO TRANSMIT ROLE -- PRESS 'R' TO SWITCH BACK\n\r");

      role = role_ping_out;
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
      radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);

    }
    else if ( c == 'R' && role == role_ping_out )
    {
      printf("*** CHANGING TO RECEIVE ROLE -- PRESS 'T' TO SWITCH BACK\n\r");

      role = role_pong_back;
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
      radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
      radio.printDetails();
    }
  }
}
// vim:cin:ai:sts=2 sw=2 ft=cpp
```

Raspberry Pi:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "../RF24.h"

RF24 radio("/dev/spidev0.0",8000000 , 25);  //spi device, speed and CSN,only CSN is NEEDED in RPI

const int role_pin = 7;
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E9LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };

typedef enum { role_ping_out = 1, role_pong_back } role_e;

const char* role_friendly_name[] = { "invalid", "Ping out", "Pong back"};

role_e role;

void setup(void)
{
    printf("\n\rRF24/examples/pingpair/\n\r");
    printf("ROLE: %s\n\r",role_friendly_name[role]);

    radio.begin();

    radio.setRetries(15,15);

    radio.setChannel(0x4c);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);

    if ( role == role_ping_out )
    {
        radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
        radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
        radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
    }

    radio.startListening();
    radio.printDetails();
}

void loop(void)
{
    if (role == role_ping_out)
    {
        radio.stopListening();

        unsigned int  mess = 41;

        unsigned long time = __millis();
        printf("Now sending: %lu ---  ...",mess);
        bool ok = radio.write( &mess, sizeof(unsigned int));

        if (ok)
            printf(" ok...");
        else
            printf("failed.\n\r");

        radio.startListening();

        unsigned long started_waiting_at = __millis();
        bool timeout = false;
        while ( ! radio.available() && ! timeout ) {
            __msleep(30); //add a small delay to let radio.available to check payload
            if (__millis() - started_waiting_at > 200 )
                timeout = true;
        }

        if ( timeout )
        {
            printf("Failed, response timed out.\n\r");
        }
        else
        {
            unsigned long got_time;
            radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );
            printf("Got response %lu, round-trip delay: %lu\n\r",got_time,__millis()-got_time);
        }

        sleep(1);
    }

    if ( role == role_pong_back )
    {
        if ( radio.available() )
        {
            unsigned long got_time;
            bool done = false;
            while (!done)
            {

                done = radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

                printf("Got payload %lu...",got_time);

                delay(20);
            }

            radio.stopListening();

            printf("Sent response.\n\r");
            radio.write( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

            radio.startListening();
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setup();
    while(1)
        loop();

    return 0;
}


// vim:cin:ai:sts=2 sw=2 ft=cpp
```

Comment: I didn't post the Arduino code because I know for a fact that works. I tested it across two arduinos.

Comment: It's important because I believe the pipes have to be the same.

Comment: The pipes are the same. I use the same library for the arduino and the Pi. I basically copied and pasted from my arduino code and just changed the necessary parts.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted ?

Comment: As a note, the code I posted works. If you connected the pins as indicated and run the code on both devices, they will communicate.  This will help you determine if your radios are still good (I have had one go bad before). If it does not work, then its your radio(s).

Comment: I haven't had the time yet but I will try it soon.

Comment: I wired the line according to the post. however the chip gets really hot. but if I connect to the GPIO pin that is also 3.3(its one of the DNC chip) and it doesn't heat up but it doesn't work either. When the chip is hot its returning max values of everything.

Comment: Did you run the code I posted or yours?

Comment: I ran your code.

Comment: Im confused. The on chip voltage regulator accepts supply voltages from 1.9 to 3.6V. My post tells you to use the 3.3 pin on the raspberry pi for VCC. And what max values are you taking about? The code I gave you calculates the time in milli-seconds.

Comment: The max values for an unsigned int and ints.

Comment: Can you post an example output? I am wondering if you fried the RF. If you applied 5v to it, I think you did. I accidentally did this to one of my RF units. To test if the RF is good or bad, swap the one you have connected to the Arduino (since you know it works) with the one connected to the Raspberry Pi. Post you findings.

Comment: I didn't fry the chip. I just connected the chip to an extra arduino I had and ran some code that I know works and it Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

stumbled across this question while looking for something else, had been working with the nrf24l01 modules and pi's and with the code from https://github.com/TMRh20 worked perfectly for me. Arduino <-> Pi and Pi <-> Pi although i was using it as a tcp/ip link.